# Why we are not allowed to turn rubber band inside out in obvious way?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Why we are not allowed to turn rubber band (easy visualization of inside and outside of circle) inside out in easy and obvious way (turning rubber band to flat annulus  then turning to the other side) and it is not acceptable for turning circle inside out?

Comment: Who says you cannot deform a rubber band to examine its topological properties.  Just don't overstretch it!

Comment: you'll create a corner; have you seen that youtube video on inverting a sphere